# Convert OpenSSL IV to hex?

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm working on a tool that applies AES-128 encryption to HLS streams. Here is my Ruby code so far:

```
aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
aes.encrypt
aes_key = aes.random_key
aes_iv = aes.random_iv
```

Now, when I output aes_iv, it gives me what is clearly just binary data that my shell env struggles to translate into text. That makes sense. What I need is to convert this to a hex representation.

The IV must be indicated in the HLS manifest file as such:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="crypt0.key",IV=0xdc03cfac7ea13f69dd49c1411c14c264
```

The IV attribute on that line is described as such:

*"The value is a hexadecimal-integer that specifies the Initialization Vector to be used with the key.  The IV attribute appeared in protocol version 2."*

I have two issues:

1. How can I be sure that random_iv is setting a proper IV that is compatible with the HLS spec?
2. How can I convert the binary IV output from random_iv to the hex value needed?

I've tried doing this:

`aes_iv.unpack("H*")` and `aes_iv.unpack("h*")`, which returns something like "4b56da546d807eb0870170b4e03d77dd", which appears to be correct. However, when I specify that as the IV, the video cannot be played.

I've isolated the issue to IV, as if I don't call random_iv and specify the IV of "00000000000000000000000000000000", it works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like I was able to get it working using aes_iv.unpack("H*"). I think I was viewing some older video files from earlier failed trials.

I'm pretty clueless as to why H* works and h* does not work. I see there is a description of it here: http://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack, which explains the difference is low nibble vs high nibble, but not sure what the difference here is.